# Flutter setState({}) is updating the Widget State even after a delay when the variable is changed

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

The thing I am doing is calling **setState()** method and then updating the state after a delay of 5 seconds. Even then, i am seeing the State getting updated.

```
setState(() {
  print("callback");
});
sleep(const Duration(seconds: 5));
_randomNumber = Random().nextInt(100);
print("Number : $_randomNumber");
```

As you can see after the delay, _randomNumber is changing & I have set this _randomNumber value to a Text Widget. After 10 seconds, text is getting updated with the new _randomNumber. Then what is the use of calling **setState(() {})** & wrapping the state changes only inside setState() ?

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? why do you call `sleep` function at all? did you notice that this is a blocking function (try to set `seconds: 15` and interact with any components like buttons, text fields etc)?

Comment: @pskink this is not production ready code. I am just checking out how setState() method works, so trying out different things

Comment: use "await" with your sleep function make it future implementations "await sleep(const Duration(seconds: 5));" or "await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:5))"

Comment: so, what is not clear after you deleted blocking `sleep` function?

Comment: @pskink My doubts are cleared now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is the way to *force* an update immediately. It is your chance to *control* the timing. It is not the *only* way that the tree can get rebuild. Any number of other events can result in another call to your build function. But then you are not in control. It will get updated as a side-effect of something else happening.